# How to render a Component if the prop is a component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-props, react-component

I want to make a 'flexible' component, but not sure if this is a good code:

```
{
    leftText instanceof Object ? 
        leftText :
           <Text>
              { leftText }
           </Text>
}
```

So if I receive a component as props I don't want to wrap it into another component, but render the component itself. ELSE just want to wrap the prop inside a Text component.

Is there a good approach to this problem?

Comment: how about using https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#isvalidelement

Comment: Yeah, this one definitely looks alot better than instance of. Thanks for highlighting!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, your way definitely works! But just verifying if the child is an Object is very generic. You could use:

```
{
    React.IsValidElement(leftText) ? 
        leftText :
           <Text>
              { leftText }
           </Text>
}
```

Comment: You are right, this one looks a lot more clear.
Thanks!